# Custom Screen for JIRA

Tags: jira

I have several steps in my workflow where I want the user to be able to see additional fields and edit those fields.  Is there a way to have different screens for different workflows?  Not the transitions, but the steps themselves.  For instance, I have an analysis step, where I need somebody to add additional information to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Behaviours plugin can make fields readonly, hidden etc based on different statuses such as  Analysis in a workflow
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours